# Does the line-ending format of robots.txt matter?

Tags: robots.txt

Simple question: Should I make sure to use Unix line endings for my robots.txt, or does it not matter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't matter. According to the spec:

> The file consists of one or more records separated by one or more blank lines (terminated by CR,CR/NL, or NL).

- CR = Carriage Return (i.e. \r)
- CR/NL = Carriage Return/New Line (i.e. \r\n)
- NL = New Line (i.e. \n)

This means you can use `\r`. `\n`, or `\r\n` and it will work.